# Facebook API batch request using Tornado

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, tornado

I am using Tornado to issue requests to FB's API and I'd like to know if there is the possibility to send batch requests. A first inspection of the source code of facebook_request() in Tornado reveals that there's no provision for batch requests. Does anybody know if that is possible?

Comment: What exactly you need from batch requests?

Comment: let's say I want to get the user's friends along with the user's photos in a single request

Comment: Try to inherit from `tornado.auth.FacebookGraphMixin` and use `facebook_request('/fql', {'q':"<queies_list_like_in_multiquery_manual>")`.